# Remove Unnamed Columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working on an excel file and the pandas shows the excel file like this.
[image]

How do i get rid of all Unnamed rows ?

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick

```
remove_cols = [col for col in gd.columns if 'Unnamed' in col]
gd.drop(remove_cols, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the result you are getting, the Excel data doesn't start on the first row. It also starts in column B instead of column A.

If you are able to edit the Excel file, I would recommend starting your data at A1 (by removing the empty column A and the empty rows at the top using Excel), as that will make later processing much easier for everyone reading the file.

If this file is not editable (perhaps it is generated by another party), you will need to skip the first couple of rows to read the correct headings:

```py
gd = pd.read_excel(r"D:\gdp.xlsx", skiprows=3, usecols="B:L")
```